# How many checks against null is appropriate?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I've got this issue when a variable is missing a field and the user gets to see the warning that this or that variable doesn't have this or that property. In the simple case it's very straight-forward.

```
if(field)
  doSomething(field.subField);
```

However, in empirical situations, I've found myself getting to this absurd over-checking.

```
if(!data 
  || !data.records 
  || !data.records[0] 
  || !data.records[0].field 
  || !data.records[0].field.id)
    return null;
doSomething(data);
```

I mean, c'mon - the pipe-ish thingy looks like if I'm a plumber, not developer. So, I have a very strong feeling that my checks, while sufficient, might be a little bit way-too-overkill. Is there a convention in JS on when to perform a check?

Comment: If you need to do this constantly your code probably has more issues than you think.

Comment: There is a library that may help: https://github.com/jclem/steeltoe

Comment: How about using a [`try/catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) instead?

Comment: +1 @Blazemonger. I think Python has a rationale to favor that, but I don't remember what it's called.

Comment: From your code, it looks like you are validating a JSON or similar structure. If you really need to do that, I suggest refactoring your validation code into a separate function.

Comment: @Prinzhorn It's not my code. I inherited it. And yes, from the beginning it had much more issues than I thought. It doesn't anymore. Not because the code got better. It's because my expectations deteriorated. Gravely.

Comment: @Blazemonger I think I'll have to do that, for the sake of sanity. It's like saying "I'm going to cut myself" but instead of getting a better knife, one gets a better wet-wipe. But hey, the customer decides what they pay for, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to just come out with a controversial opinion.

In JavaScript, don't bother checking for `null` values in places where this realistically shouldn't occur.  In other words, your idea of checking each nested property for nulls is a bit overkill, and only serves to complicate your script.

In my experience, I've learned to *just let the script error occur*.  This is somewhat counter-intuitive to someone writing C code, or database code, where an unhandled `null` might crash the server or corrupt data, however in the script world, better to find out about your error sooner than later.  If your page continues to load with no indication that something unexpected occurred, it will just manifest itself in the form of weird bugs later on when the user clicks on a button or submits a form.

**My Advice**:

Check for `null` *only* if you're willing to do something about it.  If you have a web service that might return a `null` if something goes wrong, then check for that and display an error message.  If you get back a non-null value, assume it's a valid value and continue on.  There's no reason to litter your entire script with null checking that won't actually bring any real benefit to your program.

Comment: The problem arises when the customer is sick and tired of getting the error messages and judges each such as an end of the world. Now, I've taken over someone else's code so I'll have to leave with the constant "and there is an error again"-cloud over my head. generally, however, I like your thinking. I'll probably just throw in a try/catch and report the errors to me only, sparing the user from being whacked with the error messages. Thanks!

Comment: Most browsers support the `window.onerror` event as well, so you can trap this and log quietly.

Comment: Didn't know about that. You mean that I could go `window.onerror = function(){ ... }` **inside** `window.onload` method?! Or should it be placed on the same level, parallelly to it? And is it guaranteed to catch all the errors or need I still use *try-catch*?

Comment: Yea probably parallel to it would be best.  I dunno if it's *guaranteed* to catch all errors, it's supported differently in each browser.  You might want to use `try/catch` if you needed to catch everything.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would make sure that if an object exists, it always has a basic set of properties that makes it usable.

For example, if the variable `data` has a value at all, it would be an object that has `records` property that always is an array, even if it is empty. If the array contains anything, it should always be objects that has a `field` property, which is an object that always has an `id` proprty. That would cut down the checks to:

```
if (!data || data.records.length == 0) {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I like the idea. However, as I commented below, I had the joy of taking over the project after a less savvy coder and the cusomter is not willing to pay for a redevelopment. They only pay us for "fixing and patching". In retrospective, I shouldn't have agreed to the project but I was thinking "hey, it's just JS, how hard can that be to make some bug fixes". Now I'm standing here like an ass...

Comment: Javascript, in my experience,is the most prone environment to mad approaches, crazy code, features missunderstandings and if course... very difficult to debug.

Comment: This approach will cause uncaught errors if `records` is undefined. If you really need to catch all errors use a `try/catch`.

Comment: @KubaHoluj: You are missing the point. If you use the approach presented in the answer the `records` property is never undefined.